# How do I properly create a unit test for a class method while stubbing other methods in Scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a class and a method I am testing (`SUTClass.a()` in the example solution below). I want to create a test case that:

1. runs the body of `a()` while subordinated methods are stubbed (`b()`, `c()`)
2. verify that `b()` and `c()` have been called exactly one time

The reason to stub methods that are not under test is that they could do some expensive disk/network operation. Also, in unit testing, you are *supposed* to isolate the code under test as much as possible.

In a solution I came up with I inject stubbed `b()` and `c()` as parameters to `a()`. However, if there are more methods to stub (think of `d()`, `e()` etc) the solution becomes a mess. Is there a better way?

As an alternative solution (when class under test is a Scala `object`) it is advised to create file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`. However I consider it a poor approach.

Related posts:

- https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#mocking-scala-object

Solution:

```
import org.mockito.MockitoSugar.{doNothing, mock, times, verify}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

trait SUTClassMethods {
  def a( b: ()=>Unit, c: ()=>Unit )
  def b()
  def c()
}
class SUTClass extends SUTClassMethods {
  def a( b: () => Unit = b, c: () => Unit = c ): Unit = {
    println("Hello from a()")
    b()
    c()
  }
  def b(): Unit = println("Actual implementation of b()")
  def c(): Unit = println("Actual implementation of c()")
}

class DependencyInjectionTest extends FlatSpec {
  behavior of "a()"
  it should "make call to b() and c() but actual implementations must not be executed" in {
    val mockSUTClass = mock[SUTClassMethods]
    doNothing.when(mockSUTClass).b()
    doNothing.when(mockSUTClass).c()
    (new SUTClass).a(mockSUTClass.b, mockSUTClass.c)
    verify(mockSUTClass, times(1)).b()
    verify(mockSUTClass, times(1)).c()
  }
}
```

I am using Scala 2.11 and here is excerpt from my `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.16.32" % Test
```

Comment: I think this highlight a bad code design and/or bad tests practices. Why mock b and c? If there's a good reason to mock b and c, they should probably live in dedicated class(es).

Comment: Well, I think in unit testing you _want_ to mock everything but the method under test. Another reason: b() and c() could be performing some expensive disk or network operation I don't want to execute. Or I want to return a particular value/data in b() to simulate some paritular test case.

Comment: Have a look at a spy rather then mock. It allows partial stubbing of a real object.

Comment: @serge678 no, when you are mocking with mocking frameworks you can **only** _mock everything except the class under test_. To be able to mock _only method under test_ you'd **have to** have a single-method interface (which is what some people advocate). More reasonable approach is based on composition when you inject behavior to mock (not necessarily by mocking framework) using method parameter or class constructor. Attempting to mocking inheritance is neither possible nor reasonable.

Comment: Thanks @tentacle, I will have a look into a spy framework.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, not sure if I understand the answer. You are suggesting an approach based on composition when I inject behavior to a mock. Basically, in the solution presented I am taking a real class, real method  `a()` and inject other stubbed methods by passing them as parameters. True, I don't have tot use any inheritance (like trait SUTClassMethods). I don't have to use a mock framework. I can directly pass to a() a stubbed implementation that matches a's signature.